# Android studio shows error whenever I add new fragment or java file

Tags: java, android-studio

Whenever I add a new java file or fragment to the android studio it shows error automatically but works completely fine.

Here is my code :

[image]

Comment: the error is occurring just because of failed to import `R.java` files.

Comment: see the line number 26, `R.layout.`. move your cursor at R and press alt enter to import it.
THanks